# Need explanation of some behaviours in this very simple program

Tags: c++

I was solving exercises to pass the time and came across these behaviours in this very simple program:

**What the program does:**

> Implement a little guessing game called (for some obscure reason)
>   “Bulls and Cows.” The program has a vector of four different integers
>   in the range 0 to 9 (e.g., 1234 but not 1122) and it is the user’s
>   task to discover those numbers by repeated guesses. Say the number to
>   be guessed is 1234 and the user guesses 1359; the response should be
>   “1 bull and 1 cow” because the user got one digit (1) right and in the
>   right position (a bull) and one digit (3) right but in the wrong
>   position (a cow). The guessing continues until the user gets four
>   bulls, that is, has the four digits correct and in the correct order.

I numbered the behaviours in capital letters and will explain "what is wrong" below.

Also, the program works fine, it does not have error handling to not make it very long for this question, it also does not check if the number guessed was already guessed so you can cheat, I did not implement the solution to not make it too long for this question.

```
bool is_in_vector(std::vector<int> v, int value) {
    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i {0}; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    try {
        constexpr int bulls_success {4};
        int bulls {0};
        int cows {0};
        int lives {5};
        std::vector<int> lottery(4);
        //auto time_now {std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()};

        //Feed vector with random numbers
        std::default_random_engine ran {9}; //ran was supposed to be initialized by time_now //BEHAVIOUR EXTRA
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> factory {0,9};
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i {0}; i < lottery.size(); ++i) {
            lottery[i] = factory(ran); //BEHAVIOUR #1
        }

        //Print the answer to test the game
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i {0}; i < lottery.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << lottery[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; // Print a new line for esthetic

        int position {0};
        int guessing {0};
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Bulls: " << bulls << '\t' << "Cows: " << cows << '\n' << "Lives: " << lives << "\n\n";
            std::cout << "Enter a position in the range of 0 - 3\n";
            std::cin >> position;
            std::cout << "Enter a guessing between 0 - 9 or enter 999 to end the game\n";
            std::cin >> guessing;
            std::cout << '\n'; //Print a new line for esthetic
            if (guessing == 999) {
                std::cout << "Game ended\n";
                break;
            }
            else if (lottery[position] == guessing) {
                ++bulls;
            }
            else if (lottery[position] != guessing) {
                if (is_in_vector(lottery, guessing)) {
                    ++cows;
                }
            }
            if (!is_in_vector(lottery, guessing)) { //BEHAVIOUR #2
                std::cout << "Bang!\n";
                --lives;
            }
            if (bulls == bulls_success) {
                std::cout << "You won\n";
                break;
            }
            if (lives == 0) {
                std::cout << "You lost\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';

        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Behaviour #1:** I can't feed the vector with push_back, like this
lottery.push_back(factory(ran))
It has to be the way above. Why?

**Behaviour #2:** That part of the program does not work if I put "else if"; but if I put only "if", it works. Why?

**Behaviour Extra:** I cannot initialize default_random_engine ran with time_now, in Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition), it says I can initialize default_random_engine with "the time of the day"; if it isn't the way above, how do I do that? I also tried with just std::chrono::system_clock::now()

The extract from the book:

> By default, an engine (except possibly random_device) gives the same
>   sequence each time a program is run. That is most convenient for
>   initial debugging. If we want different sequences from an engine, we
>   need to initialize it with different values. Such initializers are
>   conventionally called “seeds.” To get an unpredictable sequence,
>   people often use the time of day (down to the last nanosecond) or something like that as the seed

It is in Chapter 24 section 7, page 917.

Comment: Kindly put one specific question per stackoverflow.com question, please.

Comment: For the extra behavior seed it with: `static_cast<long unsigned int>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())`

Comment: When you say `I can't feed the vector with push_back, like this lottery.push_back(factory(ran)) It has to be the way above.`  you don't say why you can't.  It works for me.  But note that you can't use push_back and base the loop condition on the size() of the vector unless you create the vector empty.  You could reserve space and it would still be empty but there isn't much point because you are only putting in 4 items.

Comment: To properly seed the random number generator, see the example at the bottom of this documentation page: [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Avoid using time. Time is predictable. Predictable behaviour results in predictable number generation. That can be bad. If your compiler's library implementation dropped the ball on `std::random_device`, looking at you mingw, then consider using time, but even then consider other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Because you already initialise your `vector` with space for `4` elements:

```
std::vector<int> lottery(4);
```

If you try to `push_back` into this, you will get 5 elements.

2.
Read your code carefully:

```
   else if (lottery[position] == guessing) {
                ++bulls;
   }
    else if (lottery[position] != guessing) {
        if (is_in_vector(lottery, guessing)) {
            ++cows;
        }
    }
    if (!is_in_vector(lottery, guessing)) { //BEHAVIOUR #2
```

If this position contains the correct number, then we award a `bull`. Your next `else if` deals with it not being the correct position, thus the `if` and `else if` are essentially just `if` and `else`, and nothing else can be true: `guessing` can either by `lottery[position]` or it can't be, so adding another `else if` will never get hit. What you probably want is:

```
// correct guess
else if (lottery[position] == guessing) {
    ++bulls;
// incorrect guess
} else {
    // correct number, incorrect position
    if (is_in_vector(lottery, guessing) {
        ++cows;
    }
    // nothing correct
    else {
    }
```

3.
You can seed with time like so:

```
std::default_random_engine ran(static_cast<long unsigned int>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()));
```